# pytest a script using stdin from argparse

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I have an argparse script using stdin:

```py
$ tree
.
├── go.py
└── mypytest.py
$

$ cat go.py
# echo '[{"k": ["1", "2"]}]' | python go.py -
import argparse, json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('json', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()
with args.json as f:
  obj = json.load(f)
print(obj)
$
```

The script is working well:

```
$ echo '[{"k": ["1", "2"]}]' | python go.py -
[{'k': ['1', '2']}]
$
```

I'm using pytest and https://pypi.org/project/pytest-console-scripts/ to test scripts:

```py
$ cat mypytest.py
def test_stdin(script_runner, monkeypatch):
    import io
    monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', io.StringIO('[{"k": ["1", "2"]}]'))
    ret = script_runner.run("go.py", "-", print_result=True)
    assert ret.success
    assert "k" in ret.stdout
    assert ret.stderr == ""
$
```

pytest does not succed to forward from stdin the stream to the pipe:

```
$ pytest mypytest.py 
================================================ test session starts ================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /tmp/aaaa
plugins: mock-3.10.0, cov-4.0.0, console-scripts-1.3.1
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                              

mypytest.py F                                                                                                                                                                           [100%]

=========================================
 FAILURES ===============================
____________________________________________
test_stdin[inprocess] ____________________________________________

script_runner = <ScriptRunner inprocess>, monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7fc74ba75a50>

    def test_stdin(script_runner, monkeypatch):
        import io
        monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', io.StringIO('[{"k": ["1", "2"]}]'))
        ret = script_runner.run("go.py", "-", print_result=True)
>       assert ret.success
E       assert False
E        +  where False = <pytest_console_scripts.RunResult object at 0x7fc74ba75c90>.success

mypytest.py:5: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ Captured stdout call -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Running console script: go.py -
# Script return code: 1
# Script stdout:

# Script stderr:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/envs/doc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_console_scripts.py", line 196, in exec_script
    exec(compiled, {'__name__': '__main__'})
  File "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/aaaa/go.py' mode='rt' encoding='utf-8'>", line 7, in <module>

  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode

    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

====================================== short test summary info ======================================
FAILED mypytest.py::test_stdin[inprocess] - assert False
======================================= 1 failed in 0.15s =======================================
$
```

the cmd bellow:

```
$ python -m pytest mypytest.py
```

give the same result

### more debug with `-s -v`

```
$ python -m pytest mypytest.py -v -s
================================= test session starts ==================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.4, pytest-7.2.0, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /home/luis/.pyenv/versions/doc/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /tmp/aaaa
plugins: mock-3.10.0, cov-4.0.0, console-scripts-1.3.1
collected 1 item                                                                       

mypytest.py::test_stdin[inprocess] # Running console script: go.py -
# Script return code: 1
# Script stdout:

# Script stderr:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/envs/doc/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytest_console_scripts.py", line 196, in exec_script
    exec(compiled, {'__name__': '__main__'})
  File "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/aaaa/go.py' mode='rt' encoding='utf-8'>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/home/luis/.pyenv/versions/3.10.4/lib/python3.10/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

FAILED

======================================= FAILURES =======================================
________________________________ test_stdin[inprocess] _________________________________

script_runner = <ScriptRunner inprocess>
monkeypatch = <_pytest.monkeypatch.MonkeyPatch object at 0x7f2b4307d630>

    def test_stdin(script_runner, monkeypatch):
        import io
        monkeypatch.setattr('sys.stdin', io.StringIO('[{"k": ["1", "2"]}]'))
        ret = script_runner.run("go.py", "-", print_result=True)
>       assert ret.success
E       assert False
E        +  where False = <pytest_console_scripts.RunResult object at 0x7f2b430cf610>.success

mypytest.py:5: AssertionError
=============================== short test summary info ================================
FAILED mypytest.py::test_stdin[inprocess] - assert False
================================== 1 failed in 0.14s ===================================
$
```

Comment: if you run `python -m pytest -v -s`, does it throw same error? i tried your script on mac , it ran okay till `assert ret.success` and got error at `assert "k" in ret.stdout`

Comment: `python -m pytest` does not find the test I got "no tests ran in 0.01s", I have to run `python -m pytest mypytest.py `

Comment: @user3313834 *python -m pytest does not find the test...* - That's an unrelated issue because your file doesn't match the [test discovery naming conventions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html#conventions-for-python-test-discovery). I think that what @simpleApp was suggesting was for you to try the `-s` flag.

Comment: yes @tmt I got the `-s` my question has been updated with `python -m pytest mypytest.py -v -s`